# Google Play Console - Will promoting a release to Production invalidate an existing reviewed-but-not-yet-published Production release?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have checked:

- [will open testing on Google Play overwrite the existing production app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889627/will-open-testing-on-google-play-overwrite-the-existing-production-app)
- [New Google play console - managed publishing for first app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634374/new-google-play-console-managed-publishing-for-first-app-release)

but they don't seem to answer my question.

---

I have enabled "Managed Publishing" and an existing Production release (build 6416) that's already reviewed by Google Play, and only needs to be published manually (because I had managed publishing turned on)

I created a Closed testing release (build 6425) and is currently undergoing review.

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnGMC.png).

**Questions:**

If I promote build 6425 from Closed testing track to Production track:

1. will it invalidate or remove build 6416 and reset back to the reviewing stage? And it means, I can no longer publish 6416 without waiting until 6425 is reviewed completely?
2. Or can I still publish build 6416 without waiting for 6425? And 6416 will only be replaced by 6425 after the review process of 6425 is finished?

I'm raising this because my team would like to have the option to release 6416 immediately without waiting for 6425 fixes ONLY if there's a need (and still within the deadline). But ideally, we'd like to release 6425 but we are hesitant because of the uncertainty of the review duration.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE/SELF-ANSWER:**

So in the end I tried this in a dummy app then in our final project, and was able to confirm that:

1. No, creating another release will not delete/invalidate an already reviewed-but-not-yet-published release.
2. Yes, after 6425 is reviewed, it will just override the not-yet-published 6416 release.

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71pNU.png) of ongoing review and an already reviewed release but not yet published.

Comment: added self-answer. treat this as closed